# Installing gems on locally to the project folder for portability reasons

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to containerize a rails project. For some reason, I want to have a rails project that I can copy and paste to another machine so I can run it on the other machine without having to run "bundle install" on the other machine. Is there a way to install all dependencies in the project folder, deploy the project folder to other machine and directly run it from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. From your project's top-level folder run

```
bundle install --path vendor/cache
```

This will install all the required gems to a subfolder under `vendor`. You can then copy the entire project folder to your other machine and all the necessary gems will come along with it.

To execute commands that rely on these locally-installed gems you'll need to prefix each command with `bundle exec`, e.g.

```
bundle exec rails server
```

Alternatively, you could use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) to manage this whole process (deploying the project to a remote server and installing the necessary gems) for you.

Comment: Great answer Simon. +1 for such a succinct answer!